# Evalutate the given contour integral using Green's theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Green's theorem. Let $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ be continuous with continuous partials in a simply connected closed region $R$ whose boundary is the contour $C$. Then
> $$\int_C Pdx+Qdy = \int\int_R (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dxdy$$ where$C$ is traversed in the positive sense.

> Evaluate $$\int_C\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}dy$$ along the circle $|z|=r$. Here $z\in\Bbb C$

First of all, the answer provided in the book is $\pi r^2/4$. I tried to evaluate the problem using the above green's theorem. But I can't use that because the partial derivative of the integrant w.r.t. $x$ is $\frac{y^2(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ which is not continuous at the origin (no limit exists). But if I ignore this, and just use green's theorem, then the value is $\pi r^2/4$. Is this a problem error? Or other way to prove this?

I post the title 'using green's theorem' but the original question didn't say that. But in the corresponding chapter, It says green's theorem and I'm quite sure the purpose is to use green's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But given the singularity at the origin, why not go directly for contour integral along the path $|z| = r$ instead of applying Green's theorem which results in a region that passes through origin?

Parametrize $x = r \cos t, y = r \sin t$. So, $dy = r \cos t \ dt$

$\displaystyle \int_C\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}dy = r^2 \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2t \sin^2t \ dt = \frac{r^2}{8} \int_0^{2\pi} (1-\cos4t) \ dt = \frac{\pi r^2}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Here, we have

$$P(x,y)=0\text{ and } Q(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

So, the integrale becomes
$$\int \int_R \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}
dxdy=$$

$$\int \int \frac{ y^2(x^2+y^2)-2x^2y^2}{r^4}$$

$$=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_\epsilon ^r\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2(t)(\sin^2(t)-\cos^2(t))RdRdt$$

Answer (score 0):

hamam_Abdallah's answer is correct, but you seem concerned about why it works and so I'm going to give a bit of a more rigorous justification.
There are two main ways to do this. The first is to note that we can make $Q$ a  continuous function because $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} = 0$ (which can be calculated using polar coordinates. If we define $f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 0 & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$, and we show that $f$ has continuous partial derivatives, then we can directly apply Green's theorem to $f$. If we take this approach, we technically don't even need the limiting process as it is in some sense "just an application of Green's Theorem to $f$."

There is a second, more complicated, and more general method to solve this problem which does involve limits. To begin, I'm going to establish some notation. $A_\epsilon$ is going to represent the annulus with outer radius $r$ and inner radius $\epsilon$, and $\gamma_\epsilon$ the circle with radius epsilon (all centered on zero). I'm also going to refer to things in terms of $P$ and $Q$ for now. We have that the $\partial A_\epsilon$ has two components, $C$ and $\gamma_\epsilon$. We can apply green's theorem to say that $$
\int_C P dx + Q dy = \iint_{A_\epsilon} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dA - \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} P dx - Q dy
$$. Now we can take the limit of both sides to get that
$$
\int_C P dx + Q dy = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left(\iint_{A_\epsilon} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dA - \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} P dx - Q dy\right)
$$.
Well, what are the values of our limits. $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\iint_{A_\epsilon} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dA$ is exactly the same as what hamam_abdallah was calculating. But what happens to $\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} P dx - Q dy$. Well this is the same thing as $\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} (P, Q) \cdot \vec{T} dt$ where $\vec T$ is the unit tangent vector for $\gamma_\epsilon$. We know that
$$
\left|\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} (P, Q) \cdot \vec{T} dt\right|\leq \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} |(P,Q)\cdot \vec T| dt 
\leq \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} |(P,Q)| dt
$$
But in this partiuclar case, $|(P,Q)| = \left|\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|= \left| \frac{r^3\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{r^2}\right|\leq r$. Pluging this in, we get that $\left|\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} (P, Q) \cdot \vec{T} dr\right| \leq \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} r dt = 2\pi \epsilon^2$ (as $r=\epsilon$ on $\gamma_\epsilon$). Using this, we get that $\left |\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} P dx - Q dy\right| \leq \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} 2\pi\epsilon^2$ = 0, and so $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} P dx - Q dy = 0$. But if we go all the way back to the beginning, we get that
$$\int_C P dx +Q dy = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \iint_{A_\epsilon} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dA - \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} P dx - Q dy = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \iint_{A_\epsilon} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dA.$$
This gives us that the answer calculated above is correct.